# can I use apnagent to send push notifications with only a PEM and passphrase?

Tags: node.js, apple-push-notifications, apnagent

Can you connect with apnagent only using a single .pem and passphrase?  Or do I need a separate key .pem too?

I'm a little ignorant of the different cert files and their uses so I am not sure if my mistake is trying to only use the .pem file and a passphrase or if I am making some other mistake.

When I run the following code, I get no error or successful response.  Only my "waiting for events...."

```
'use strict'
const apnagent = require('apnagent')
const join = require('path').join
const certFile = join(__dirname,'/../certs/mint-APN-dev.pem')
const deviceToken = '<token>'
const passphrase = '<passphrase>'

let agent = module.exports = new apnagent.Agent()
agent
    .set('cert file',certFile)
    .set('passphrase',passphrase)
    .enable('sandbox')

agent.connect(function (err) {

    if (err && err.name === 'GatewayAuthorizationError') {
        console.log('Authentication Error: %s', err.message)
        process.exit(1)
    }


    else if (err) {
        throw err
    }


    var env = agent.enabled('sandbox')
        ? 'sandbox'
        : 'production'

    console.log('apnagent [%s] gateway connected', env)
})

// keep it running for a bit to give it time to succeed or fail
let id = setInterval(function() {
    console.log('Waiting for events...')
    count++
    if (count > 18) clearInterval(id)
}, 5000)
```

Comment: Obviously here I am only trying to connect, not send a message.

Answer (score 0):

nevermind. I answered my own question after more testing. with a .pem file, you have to have both key and cert. but with a .p12 file, you can have only one file